# Dataframe column match with list and create new columns

Tags: python, string, list, dataframe, string-matching

I have data frame DF column A , check how much List `a=["enter", 'Enter', 'Click', 'click']` available in data frame column,
and create another column B  on the same names. i want to my data frame to look like this :

```
DF=       A
       "enter Username"
       "click UserBox"
       "Enter Password"
       "Click login"
       "click checkbox"
       "Enter Phonenumber"
```

OUTPUT :

```
DF=       A                         B
       "enter Username"             enter
       "click UserBox"              click
       "Enter Password"             Enter
       "Click login"                Click
       "click checkbox"             click
       "Enter Phonenumber"          Enter
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) with [`set intersection`](https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_set_intersection.asp) using operator `&`:

```
In [1003]: s = set(a)
In [994]: df['B'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x: (set(x.split()) & s).pop() if len((set(x.split()) & s)) > 0 else '')

In [995]: df
Out[995]: 
                   A      B
0     enter Username  enter
1      click UserBox  click
2     Enter Password  Enter
3        Click login  Click
4     click checkbox  click
5  Enter Phonenumber  Enter
```

Comment: If my string in Column A is  big like , A "enter Username to the file", click UserBox to the item ,Enter Password to the field

Comment: @soumyapanigrahi Even if Column `A` is a big string, my solution will still work perfectly.

Comment: Getting, KeyError: 'pop from an empty set'

Comment: @soumyapanigrahi Please check my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks buddy !! it is looks fine now